# Select2 angular ui not working

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am trying to have images in select2 multi select from this [tutorial](http://xcellerant.net/2014/10/28/formatting-select2-options-in-angular/)
, but its not working at all.

Since I am not very much used to of plnkr, I might be missing something in [`my example plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/FK8iCk6g07un4Sk0XCZP?p=preview)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have to display `{{group.text}}` i.e `<option ng-repeat="group in options" value="{{group.text}}">{{group.text}}</option>`

Comment: working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ahBPZ8FY37I7riiaZsdG?p=preview)

Comment: OMG, what a silly mistake! thanks @gauravbhavsar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @gaurav said:

Change

```
<option ng-repeat="group in options" value="{{group.text}}">{{group}}</option>
```

To:

```
<option ng-repeat="group in options" value="{{group.text}}">{{group.text}}</option>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/StzWH4EKZWJkWdkwFB04?p=preview)